# Shorthand for looping through an object of objects

Tags: javascript, loops, object

I have an object of objects, similar to this:

```
{
  file0: {
    body: {
      prop1: 'abc',
      prop2: 123
    }
  },
  file1: {
    header: {
      prop1: 987,
      prop2: 'xyz',
      prop3: 0
    }
  }
}
```

I want to loop through the top level objects (`file0`, `file1`, etc), and then build up the following dynamically:

`window['body'] = { prop1: 'abc', prop2: 123 }`

`window['header'] = { prop1: 987, prop2: 'xyz', prop3: 0 }`

etc, etc, etc

I got this working by using the following:

```
export const registerComponents = components => {
  for (let component in components) {
    window[Object.keys(components[component])[0]] = components[component][Object.keys(components[component])[0]]
  }
}
```

Questions:

(1) Is this the best and most optimal way of achieving this?

(2) Is there another/better way to loop objects besides `for in`?

(3) Is there a shorthand way to reference the object properties?

Comment: Consider removing questions 1&2 ("what's the best...")? As they will lead to opinionated answers.

Comment: best in terms of speed seems objective to me :D

Comment: ok.. check out the speed comparisons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign the nested objects to `window` without iterating the object.

```js
const
    object = { file0: { body: { prop1: 'abc', prop2: 123 } }, file1: { header: { prop1: 987, prop2: 'xyz', prop3: 0 } } };

Object.values(object).forEach(o => Object.assign(window, o));

console.log(body);
console.log(header);
```

Comment: oo, i put the code i was gonna put and it's close fight to urs >:D

Answer (score 0):

I'll just show the speed difference between the options.

Enjoy **:D**

```js
//your code
const registerComponents = components => {
  for (let component in components) {
    window[Object.keys(components[component])[0]] = components[component][Object.keys(components[component])[0]]
  }
}

//100k dude code
const hisCode=(components)=>{
  Object.values(components).forEach(o => Object.assign(window, o));
}

//just for fun, my code >:D
const myCode=(components)=>{
  const x=Object.keys(components)
  for(let i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    Object.assign(window,components[x[i]])
  }
}

//speed tester
function speedTest(fn,a){
  var t1=new Date()
  for(var i=0;i<999999;i++){fn(a)}
  return new Date()-t1
}

console.log(`your code's speed is ${speedTest(registerComponents,object)} ms\n100k dude code's speed is ${speedTest(hisCode,object)} ms\nJust for fun, my code's speed is ${speedTest(myCode,object)} ms`)
```

```html
<script>
window.object = {
  file0: {
    body: {
      prop1: 'abc',
      prop2: 123
    }
  },
  file1: {
    header: {
      prop1: 987,
      prop2: 'xyz',
      prop3: 0
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and clean code.

```
const obj={ //example object
  file0: {
    body: {
      prop1: 'abc',
      prop2: 123
    }
  },
  file1: {
    header: {
      prop1: 987,
      prop2: 'xyz',
      prop3: 0
    }
  }
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach((topLevelKey) => {
      const nestedObject = Object.keys(obj[topLevelKey])[0];// 'body', 'header', etc
      window[nestedObject] = obj[topLevelKey][nestedObject];
    });
```